# Does the OP get notified when I place a bounty on their question?

Tags: support, bounties, notifications

Nobody's ever posted a bounty on any of my questions, so I have no idea. <sup>*</sup>

I did try searching for a dupe, didn't find anything.

I just started a bounty on someone else's question. Were they notified about it?

<sup>*</sup> = Plot twist: What if they have, and I just didn't notice? Depends on the answer to this question.

Comment: @Gothdo Since there is no answer there, I'm assuming the answer is **no**? To be semantic since this is [tag:support] and that is a [tag:feature-request] it's not strictly speaking a duplicate, but I guess it does answer my question.

Comment: The answer is "no". This is not strictly a duplicate, but since it's a feature request, it's rather obvious that this feature is not yet implemented (and that answers your question).

Comment: @Gothdo I 100% agree with that.